# Java Threading Issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm synchronizing on the object of the thread like this:

```
synchronized(threadObject){
    try{
       threadObject.interrupt();
    }catch(Exception ex){
       //catch error here.
    }finally{
       threadObject.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Now, my questions are:

1. It is possible to interrupt a thread
   inside a synchronized block whose
   object that was synchronized was the
   thread to be interrupted? Like in
   the sample code.
2. Can I still notify other threads
   holding the interrupted thread's
   object? Like in the sample code.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

> **It is possible to interrupt a thread inside a synchronized block whose object that was synchronized was the thread to be interrupted? Like in the sample code.**

Yes. I can't see why that wouldn't work. The `synchronized` keyword is quite orthogonal to the `interrupt` method. (Note that contrary to `await` and `notify`, you're *not* required to own the objects monitor when calling `interrupt`.)

> **Can I still notify other threads holding the interrupted thread's object? Like in the sample code.**

Yes, you can call `notifyAll` on any object as long as you own the objects monitor. Again, the `wait/notify`-mechanism is quite orthogonal to the `interrupt` method.

---

Your question seem to indicate that you've misunderstood the use of `synchronized`. The usual use-case is to synchronize on an object representing some resource which you like to avoid concurrent access to. The *thread itself* rarely represent such resource.

Answer (score 0):

The object works as it normally does. The only stipulation is that other threads that synchronize on threadObject's monitor will block until you're complete with your thread. So yes, you can do both of those.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes: But you don't really need to have the lock before calling interrupt.
2. Yes

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is yes.

However, there is something a bit strange about your example.  I've never come across a case where you would use a `Thread` as a primitive lock.  And it what you are doing in the example doesn't seem to achieve anything.

- If `threadObject` is the same as `Thread.currentThread()`, then the call to `interrupt()` will just set this thread's interrupted flag ... which be noticed in that code fragment.
- if `threadObject` is some other `Thread` object then that thread will be interrupted.  But we can't see (here) the code that that thread will be executing, and we don't know if it will be waiting on `threadObject`.  If not the `interrupt()` and `notify()` well got to different threads ...

The bottom line is that you wouldn't normally use a Thread object as a lock, and you wouldn't normally send use an interrupt() as an *ersatz* notify().

(Maybe this example is not intended to represent a real use-case.)